# Is this the correct way of creating a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I was researching how to make a matrix in Python using `numpy` and have the user enter values to it.

I came across a video that used a certain code, after working and understanding it, I wrote something similar and I got the same output.

I wanted to know what is the difference between both codes and which is better and wiser and simple to use.

Here both the code creates a 3x3 matrix

Code from the video:

```
import numpy as np

r = 3
c = 3

a = np.zeros((r, c), dtype=np.int64)

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        num = int(input('Enter the entries: '))
        a[i][j] = num 
print(a)
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np

r = 3
c = 3

a = np.zeros((r,c),dtype=np.int64)

for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        num = int(input('Enter the entries: '))
        a[i][j] = num
print(a)
```

Comment: the only difference is in the `range`? Are you asking what is more "correct" in the the range?

Comment: @DavidS yep the range, why did he have to complicate the range dis much, wen it cud be done like dis in a simple way?

Comment: See my answer for different approach to iterate over the array that doesn't involve the range.

Comment: Asking your user for entries, especially one at a time, gets tedious if the size is at all large.  It's ok for learning.  If you just need a test array, do something simple like `a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different way that is the same but simpler to read is:

```
import numpy as np

r = 3
c = 3

a = np.zeros((r,c),dtype=np.int64)
for idx in np.ndindex(r, c):
    num = int(input('Enter the entries: '))
    a[idx] = num
print(a)
```

Again this is basically the same as your code but utilizing `np.ndindex` and it's applicable to `ndarray`. So if you will need to increase the dimension of the matrix for some reason it will be easier in that way rather then adding another `for` loop